# mongod command with --dbpath destination (should be the db of my unifi controller) is not working, what is wrong? Invalid command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
debollekes@des-MacBook-Air ~ % mongod --dbpath arg /Users/debollekes/Library/Application Support/UniFi 
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.934+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.935+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.937+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.938+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.939+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.939+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-28T21:55:15.939+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
Invalid command: /Users/debollekes/Library/Application
Options:
  --networkMessageCompressors arg (=snappy,zstd,zlib)
                                        Comma-separated list of compressors to 
                                        use for network messages

General options:
```

Comment: correct command is: mongod --dbpath="/Users/debollekes/Library/Application Support/UniFi/db"

Comment: You can answer your own below under "Your Answer".  This will help other users see that there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is:

```bash
mongod --dbpath="/Users/debollekes/Library/Application Support/UniFi/db"
```